# inline underneath subscripts

Tags: subscripts, inline

Here is a piece of text I am working on:

```
this is written as $\mathbf{p} \underset{s}{\sim}\mathbf{\bar{p}}$, and associated with the equivalence class $E(\underset{s}{\sim},\mathbf{p})=\{ \mathbf{\bar{p}}\in\Omega :\mathbf{p} \underset{s}{\sim} \mathbf{\bar{p}} \}$
```

This produces a line of text looking like this (unrelated to theis problem, this is in some text italicized for being a definition):

[image]

I would like to make the s underneath the \sim closer to it so that it doesn't stick out beneath the brackets so much.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal-but-complete, compilable piece of code instead of just a snippet?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution based on `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myunderset}[2]{\underset{\raisebox{0.67ex}{$\smash{\scriptstyle #1 }$}}{#2}}
 \usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\usepackage{accents} 
\begin{document}

\noindent This is written as $\mathbf{p} \myunderset{s}{\sim}\mathbf{\bar{p}}$, and associated with the equivalence class $E(\myunderset{s}{\sim},\mathbf{p})=\{ \mathbf{\bar{p}}\in\Omega :\mathbf{p} \underset{s}{\sim} \mathbf{\bar{p}} \} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With some lower level programming:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\undersim}[1]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\under@sim{#1}}}
\newcommand{\under@sim}[2]{%
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr$\m@th#1\sim$\cr$\m@th\demote@style{#1}#2$\cr}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\demote@style}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
  \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is written as $\mathbf{p} \undersim{s} \bar{\mathbf{p}}$
and associated with the equivalence class 
\[
E(\undersim{s},\mathbf{p})=\{ \bar{\mathbf{p}}\in\Omega :
  \mathbf{p} \undersim{s} \bar{\mathbf{p}} \}
\]

$\sim\undersim{t}\undersim{A}X_{\undersim{s}}$

\end{document}
```

I changed all `\mathbf{\bar{p}}` to `\bar{\mathbf{p}}`, which is semantically more correct.

In the last line I show different examples, including the fact that `\undersim` scales correctly in subscripts.

[image]